# Bind a static Method to a CheckBox and pass a parameter to it

Tags: .net, wpf, checkbox, mvvm, data-binding

I have a checkbox and I want to run my method `OnCheckBoxChanged` if the checkbox changed, now I do it like this:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="myCheckBox" 
          Content="Run my command"
          IsChecked="SetMyCheckBoxState" 
          Checked="OnCheckBoxChanged"
          Unchecked="OnCheckBoxChanged"/>
```

and in code behind:

```
private void SetMyCheckBoxState()
{
    return Helper.GetState();
}

private void OnCheckBoxChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (myCheckBox.IsChecked)
        //my logic 1 
   else
        //my logic 2
}
```

I want to do it more in a MVVM style, something like this:

```
   public static class Helper
   {
        public static bool GetState()
        {
            var state = //My logic;
            return state; 
        }

        public static void OnCheckBoxChanged(bool state)
        {
            if (state)
                 //my logic 1 
            else
                 //my logic 2
        }
   }
```

And code xaml would look like this:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="myCheckBox" 
          Content="Run my command"
          IsChecked="{Binding Path=Helper.GetState(), Mode=TwoWay}" 
          Checked="{Binding Path=Helper.OnCheckBoxChanged(How to pass a state here ?)}"
          Unchecked="{Binding Path=Helper.OnCheckBoxChanged()}"/>
```

My question is how to pass a checkbox state to `Checked="{Binding Path=Helper.OnCheckBoxChanged(How to pass a state here ?)}"`

And how to make it work, what am I missing here?

Comment: Why not use a property of type bool? then do your logic in get and set, then value will always tell you whats coming (true or false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean property to bind with IsChecked of check box

```
private bool _isSelected;
public bool IsSelected{
    get { return _isSelected; }
    set {
        if(_isSelected == value) return;

        _isSelected = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(()=> IsSelected);
    }
}
```

And you can bind this property to IsChecked which will give you the state of check box in your view model

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know how MVVM works, in general. Let's say your CheckBox DataContext is your ViewModel. Then:

In ViewModel:

```
private bool state;
public bool State
{
  get
  {
    return state;   
  }
  set
  {
    state = value;
    OnCheckBoxChanged(value);
    OnPropertyChanged("State");
  }
}
```

And in XAML:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="myCheckBox" 
      Content="Run my command"
      IsChecked="{Binding Path=State, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going for an mvvm style, then you really shouldn't be calling methods from in your view. Instead, you should be binding to properties.
So for your checkbox:

```
<CheckBox Content="Run my command" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsCheckBoxTicked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

and in your viewmodel the property:

```
public bool IsCheckBoxTicked
{ 
    get { return _isCheckBoxTicked;}
    set { _isCheckBoxTicked = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged(IsCheckBoxTicked);
          //run any methods you want here.
        }
```

The idea is that when you change the checkbox value, the view will notify the viewmodel and update the property.

Note: you will need to look up how to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged onto your viewmodel